# How would you explain merges with ClearCase?

Tags: version-control, versioning, clearcase

I'm a developer who has never needed to worry about the implementation of source control systems / branching / merging etc... I'm searching for book which explains these concepts but is aimed at clearcase users.

From searching amazon -  the book "[IBM ClearCase 7.0: Master the Tools that Monitor, Analyze and Manage Software Configurations by Marc Girod and Tatiana Shpichko (26 Apr 2011)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=clearcase&x=0&y=0)" seems to b a good read.

Any recommendations ?

Thanks.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the title in order to make the question more in line with the FAQ of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find a good introduction regarding merges in ClearCase with "[How files and directories are merged](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/how_merge_file_dir.htm)"

[image: merge]

The particularity of a merge with ClearCase is in its **directory management**.
As explained in "[What are the basic clearcase concepts every developer should know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771)", directories are versioned too.

that means any merge in ClearCase will **merge directories first**, because it will determine the list of files needing merge (a version of a directory is a list of files).
And then it will merge files.

From there, you will find different merge scenarios explained in "[About merging in base ClearCase](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/c_about_merging.htm)".