# sync between base clearcase branch and svn branch

Tags: svn, synchronization, clearcase

I am having tough time working between svn and clearcase together. Requirement is to allow developers to make changes to a source code base in  an svn branch and also the same directory structure in a base clearcase.

So, whenever there are any changes in svn code, I need to retrofit those to a branch is clearcase called svn_branch and from there I merge it to an integration branch.

Problem comes when both developers work on same file in svn and clearcase. So, when I take the changed file from svn to clearcase svn_branch and merge it to integration, it just overwrites the previous changed and not really merge.

is there any way that a base clearcase branch and an svn branch is synchronized ?

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way that a base clearcase branch and an svn branch is synchronized ?

If the synchronization happens from SVN to ClearCase, I would indeed merge two ClearCase branches.

But if you see an override, it means ClearCase consider that the svn changes were done *after* the ClearCase changes.

Merging those two branches in that case means simply reporting the changes from the svn_branch over the CC branch.

Make sure you have versions created in the CC branch for a given file before merging that same file from the SVN branch.

Comment: to make myself more clear, changes happen in both svn branch as well as the clearcase branch and I need to bring the changes made in svn branch for the particular files to clearcase. so, I take the changed file from svn and checkout and overwrite the file into the clearcase branch .now when i merge it from clearcase branch to my clearcase integration branch, it just overwrite the changes in integration branch and any changed made to it in between in the integration branch is lost.

Comment: @user2636464 it depends on the common ancestor: if changes happened on both branches since a common ancestor, then the merge will be a real one (not an overwrite). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9534815/6309. Make sure the parent folder is the same element (not an evil twin)

Comment: yeah changes happened on both branches .svn and clearcase.so, svn uses the latest version from integration branch and make changes. clearcase also takes the same version from integration branch, make changes and merge back to integration. after this changed file froms svn arrives.now if I take that changed files and merge, its a problem isnt't it?